# Совместная работа apache и nginx

Tags: ubuntu, apache, nginx

Помогите настроить Apache.
У меня несколько сайтов включено в apache.
Есть файл ports.conf в котором прописано Listen:80 что меня почти устраивает. 
Но я хочу для одного единственного домена изменить этот самый Listen с 80 на 8080 порт.
Чего я хочу достичь: я хочу обработчиком подключить Nginx но не для всех сайтов на сервере, а только для одного.
В conf файле apache этого сайта у меня прописано

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    <Directory /var/www/html/my-domain>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ServerAdmin admin@mail.ru
    ServerName my-domain.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-domain
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-my-domain.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

В conf файле Nginx этого сайта у меня прописано

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /var/www/html/my-domain;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name my-domain.ru;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

         }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

И Apache и Nginx запущены, но при заходе на my-domain.ru в обработку включается Apache. А когда захожу на my-domain.ru:8080 работает Nginx.

Содержимое файла /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2; # Ставим число по количеству ядер

timer_resolution 100ms;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
worker_priority -5; #Увеличитвваем приоритет

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip        on;
    gzip_min_length     1100;
    #gzip_disable       "msie6";  #Быстрее, но работает только на новых версиях nginx
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_comp_level     4;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml $
    gzip_vary           on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: два процесса не могут одновременно слушать один и тот же tcp-порт, точнее, одно и то же сочетание ip:port. но в случае http-серверов вы можете проксировать соединения с одного http-сервера на другой (слушающий другой порт, естественно).

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! Удалось получить то что хотел путем добавления в conf апача нужного сайта таких директив `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>`

Comment: так напишите полноценный ответ, который мог бы помочь не только вам, но и другим.

Answer (score 1):

Перенаправить запрос на обработку через nGinx от Apache можно добавив в conf файл нужного сайта директивы

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

8080 - в данном случае порт который слушает Nginx
Также некоторая информация по директиве ProxyPreserveHost

> Обратите внимание на опцию ProxyPreserveHost, при проксировании сервер
>   подменяет параметр host в заголовке запросов на хост из опции
>   ProxyPass, при этом копирует прежний host в параметр
>   X-Forwarded-Server. При этом на некоторых движках (сайтах) может
>   неправильно работать redirect подставляя локальный адрес внутреннего
>   сервера, когда нужен внешний. Для решения этой проблемы нужно включить
>   опцию ProxyPreserveHost, тогда сервер будет оставлять реальный host
>   который пришел на текущий сервер.

Источник http://www.py-my.ru/post/4bfb3c691d41c846bc00001f

Comment: Только всё-таки обычно перенаправляют на apache от nginx, а не наоборот :)